# Why is toggle icon not working after cloning div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, icons, toggle, clone

Basically, I'm working with three tabs called 'Monday', 'Tuesday' and 'Favorites'. I have a toggle icon which is a heart. If I'm in Monday and click on the icon the empty heart turns to be filled out and it's cloned and added to the '#fav' tab. From the moment it gets there the toggle icon doesn't work at all.

I've tried:

```
clone(true, true)
```

but doesn't seem to be working well for me. I know something's wrong, so I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

I've created this fiddle, so you can experience the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/itsfranhere/nbLLc3L0/15/

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do here - can you try and explain it more clearly please?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. So, when I click on the icon ('.favorite i').. the heart gets filled out as explained above and clones the parent to the '#fav' tab. When cloned, if I click in the icon, it doesn't toggle between the two classes anymore ('fa-heart fa-heart-o'). However, if this icon is within a div that wasn't cloned it does work. @DuncanThacker

Comment: OK, thanks - I was confused before because there is a heart icon on the tab, and I didn't realise you meant the heart icon on the actual items. I'll take another look now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event listeners are not attached to the elements which created dynamically.
Hence, the click event is not fired for elements in favorites tab.

Either you need to attach event listener to the anchor elements in fav tab or use event propagation to capture the event.

```
$('div.tab-pane').on('click', '.favorite', function(e) {
 // code here
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! You're a life saver :)